# Hover a DIV, give enclosed DIV a shadow

Tags: jquery, css, html

Here's the setup : http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/rVrjY/

What I'd like to achieve is a shadow on the smaller DIV when I hover the larger DIV. Is this possible? Can it be done with CSS or is it a jquery solution, if at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of shadow you are looking for, but the idea is simple: use this selector and put your effect inside it to make it working when bigger div is hovered:

```
    .one:hover .two {
        /* put your css here */
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888;
    }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rVrjY/1/

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just add a rule like this:

```
.one:hover .two {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px #f00;   
}
```

Note that `box-shadow` may not be supported in older browsers, and the hover event won't work in devices that don't support it....but hopefully this is a starting point to get you where you need to go.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, just use:

```
​.one:hover .two {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #f90;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rVrjY/2/).